# Cannot boot on newer kernel

Tags: release-loki

After the update to kernel 4.8.0-52 my laptop doesn't boot. It does work if I select 4.4.0-78 from the grub menu.

I did update & upgrade and also run `fsck /dev/sda1` using a live USB.

This is on loki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel `4.8.0-52` is a mainline kernel. Sometimes mainline kernels just don't work with some computers. Why do you need that specific kernel? Can you try to install any other mainline kernel instead?

If you don't know why you need that kernel version then it's better to stick with the stable kernel `4.4.0-78`. Newer kernels just offer updated drivers for some hardware. If you have an old computer it won't really make a big difference on most of the cases.

Comment: I don't know either. It just appeared. I thought it was related to the new update, you're saying it's not and I should just remove it?

Comment: You probably got it from any PPA or something like that.. You can remove it yes.

Comment: I removed it and now everything's fine (except that in the process of trying to fix this, I run fsck on my boot partition and now Windows won't boot...).

Comment: Hmm why dont you try to install `boot-repair ` and use it to fix your boot problems?

Comment: I tired and it din't work. :\

Comment: You have 2 options.. 1) is try to boot windows using [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) .. is a program similar to grub, but if I'm not mistaken, refind also looks for all boot files in your hard drive, so if you happen to have an efi file to boot windows that grub is unable to detect it may work for you.

Your second option is boot elementary OS, make a copy of your important files from the windows partition and install windows again. Beware that this method will break grub so you'll need to boot a linux live usb and use it to repair your boot with boot-repair (this time will work)

Comment: Grub finds lots of efi files and I also tried to boot from them directly with a boot selector at the bios level. The issue definitely is with windows. So yeah, I will have to reinstall windows (there's nothing important there, I only use it for gaming ;).

Answer (score 0):

First boot with the working kernel.

After open the terminal and sure your system is updated by running:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

If you are sure you have the newer kernel, run

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

This command create a new initramfs image.

After that update GRUB the command

```
sudo update-grub
```

GRUB should have recognized the newer kernel now. Reboot and you should automatically use it.

Comment: Did it and know it's stuck on `Loading initial ramdisk ...`.